# Answer deleted, but I think I did, in fact, answer the question

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

https://money.stackexchange.com/posts/112048/revisions

OP asked for opinions on getting a personal loan at age 19 without actually having a job, and I gave them.  I no way shape or form did I abuse or be rude to OP.

Or is the *real* solution to close the question as POB?

Answer (score 7):

I deleted it because the question is about is it possible, not should he/she do it.

Additionally, IMO the references to "whiny, inconvenienced snowflakes" are still rude/unfriendly even though you don't directly accuse the OP of that. You're certainly suggesting it as a serious possibility.

Here's a copy of the answer, for those who can't see it directly:

> Let's say you do get the loan **before** you have the job and are
>   settled it.  AKA, you counted your chickens before they hatched.
>
> Imagine these scenarios:
>
> 1. You **don't** get the job.
> 2. Your take-home pay is a lot less than you thought it would be.
> 3. The company downsizes a month later.
> 4. You **really hate the job** (as opposed to being a whiny, inconvenienced snowflake who can't hack a little so-called
>      "oppression" by The Man).
> 5. You *actually are* a whiny, inconvenienced snowflake who can't hack a little so-called "oppression" by The Man, and ghost the job.
>
> Then... you have no income and are left with a loan payment.
>
> The bottom line is that **debt is risk**, and a 19 year old  shouldn't
>   put him or herself at risk without a job firmly in place.